# Google finding irrelevant keywords on my pages?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, keywords

I have a dynamic site with thousands of pages (database driven).  Every page has a log in link up in the header.  Not so unusual.  All of my pages have a title which is an H2 (I am changing it to H1 soon).

According to Google Webmaster Tools, "log" is the most relevant keyword on my site. How can I prevent this from happening?  Surely I'm not the only website with the words "log in" in their header, appearing on every page.

Comment: I am confused too about that irrelevant keywords. This list does not help me at all. We offer 10.000 different articles for download or buy....so my keywords are "download, buy, here, click..." completely useless... anyway, visitors are comming too..

Answer (score 1):

Just because "log" is the most relevant keyword Google has found on your site doesn't mean your site will rank well for "log" or "log in". It just means that keyword is very prevalent in your site. And that's not a bad thing. Your pages can be relevant for lots of keywords, some of which will be mundane like "log" thanks to common links in your header or footer, and others because that is what the page is about.

What you're seeing is common to most websites. You shouldn't make any changes to your site just to make that list show the keywords you want to rank well for. The two are only loosely linked.

Just focus on improving your semantic markup as that clearly is an area for improvement for your site. Then make sure you get quality links, etc. But definitely go making changes to make that list happy. That's just a clear case of focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: So then I'm confused on why Google webmaster tools shows that information at all, then?  Of what use is it?